# Forcing memory to release after running a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use a module (that I cannot modify) which contains a method that I need to use. This method returns 10GB of data, but also allocates 8GB of memory that it does not release. I need to use this method at the start of a script that runs for a long time, and I want to make sure the 8GB of memory are released after I run the method. What are my options here?

To be clear, the 8GB do not get reused by the script - i.e. if I create a large numpy array after running the method, extra memory is allocated for that numpy array.

I have considered running the method in a separate process using the multiprocessing module (and returning the result), but run into problems serializing the large result of the method - 10GB cannot be pickled by the default pickler, and even if I force multiprocessing to use pickle version 4 pickling has a very large memory overhead. Is there anything else I could do without being able to modify the offending module?

Edit: here is an example

```
from dataloader import dataloader1
result = dataloader1.get("DATA1")
```

As I understand it, dataloader is a Python wrapper around some C++ code using pybind11. I do not know much more about its internal workings. The code above results in 18GB being used. If I then run

```
del result
```

10GB gets freed up correctly, but 8GB continues being used (with seemingly no python objects existing any more).

Edit2: If I create a smallish numpy array (e.g. 3GB), memory usage stays at 8GB. If I delete it and instead create a 6GB numpy array, memory usage goes to 14GB and comes back down to 8GB after I delete it. I still need the 8GB released to the OS.

Comment: Have you tried memory profiling to see what is actually holding the memory?

Comment: You can try to serialize the 10GB data in another way like JSON.

Comment: do you really need all that data in memory? because maybe you can solve the problem lazy loading it instead of dumping everything at a time...

Comment: @norok2 See my edit. How would I go about profiling that? If my understanding is correct, the memory was allocated by the underlying C++ code and never released.

Comment: @Netwave The method returns the data all at once, and I have no control over it. That is not the problem, however - even if I then delete the result, 8GB of memory continue being used with (seemingly) no way for me to release it.

Comment: Have you tried `del dataloader1` as well? If that does not work, you may need to `import dataloader` and then inspect it (`dir(dataloader)`) to see what else may be there.

Comment: @norok2 del dataloader1 does not help.

Comment: Try to find out who owns big object(s) and delete it. Pycharm has nice debugger (community edition is free).

Comment: If allocation is made by c extension and never released, then it's either memory leak or incomplete API (lack of 'clear' method) of the library. Either way it's a bug and should be reported.

Comment: It would be good you add a bit more information on result. Is it a complex object (lists, of lists, of,...) or something simple as a numpy array?

Answer (score 2):

can you modify the function? 
If the memory is held by some module, try to reload that module, (importlib.reload) which should release the memory.

Comment: Reloading the module does not seem to help.

Comment: C extensions cannot be reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Python uses 2 different mechanisms to free memory.

1. [Reference Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) which is employed primarily and deallocates memory as soon as it is no longer needed (eg. object lost from scope).
2. [Garbage Collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), which is secondary and is used to collect objects with cyclic references (`a -> b -> c -> a`). This can be triggered using a [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect). Otherwise Python itself will decide, when to free memory.

However I would highly suggest profiling and chaning the code so that it does not use as much memory. Perhaps look into streams, or use a database.

Answer (score 0):

If the memory is not released by th gc, it is probably because an object is store in the class that created it, so an option is to find what is this big attribute in the class (by profiling) instance and assigned it to `None` which may cause the gc to release the memory.